# how to sql a record from a file that has non null values in their fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, where-clause, sql-null

Each record has 100 fields, only few of them have values and many are NULLs. If I want to display  the record with fields that has non NULL values , how do i do that ?

Example:

1. Table1 has 100 fields, one record in the table has 5 fields have non NULL values, 95 NULL values. I want to display that record.
2. Another record that has 100 fields NULLs, I dont want to display that record.

Comment: SQL queries, it doesn't display anything. The client application should decide what to display, what not.

Comment: Use a WHERE clause.  A really, big, WHERE clause...

Comment: There's no way around specifying each column in the query's `WHERE` clause. The only way to achieve this less painfully might be to generate the SQL statement dynamically as a string.

Comment: If you're just after an ad-hoc solution, you can query the table using Excel (with `SELECT * FROM`) and then have a formula in an Excel-Column that outputs `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on some smart condition.

Comment: SQL is not very good in this. If this is not an only-once problem but part of the business logic, you may consider to add an extra column to your table which holds this extra information (boolean indicating there are non-null columns or numeric to hold the number of non-null columns).

Answer (score 1):

You want records where not all columns are `null`. You will need to enumerate the column names. The most simple solution is lengthy `where` clause, like:

```
select *
from mytable 
where col1 is not null or col2 is not null or ... or colN is not null;
```

An alternative is a lateral join:

```
select t.*
from mytable
cross apply (
    select count(col) cnt
    from (values (col1), (col2), ... (colN)) as x(col)
) x
where x.cnt > 0
```

Note that the second solution requires all columns to have the same datatype - otherwise, additional casting might is needed.